# html submit button stays on the same page

Tags: html

I am writing a mobile app in html5/css/js.
On the first page index.html I made a form with a submit button that point to result.html (with formaction="result.html").
But when I open index.html in Chrome just to debug the app, the submit button doesn't bring the user to result.html, but stays on index.html.
What's wrong?
Thanks

```
<form name="userdata" method="get"> 
    <input type="number" step="any" class="hiddenbutton" name="userVolume" value="" >
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton" name="issubmitted" value="no" class="submitbutton" formmethod="get" formaction="result.html">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It doesn't work neither with:

```
<form name="userdata" method="get" action="result.html">
    <input type="number" step="any" class="hiddenbutton" name="userVolume" value="" >
    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton" name="issubmitted" value="no" class="submitbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:** I just discovered that there is no problem when I use firefox instead of Chromium (Ubuntu). Any hint on what's happening?

Comment: `<form name="userdata" method="get" action="result.html">`

Comment: `<button>`s don't have `formaction` or `formmethod` attributes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction

Comment: @RocketHazmat - makes two of us.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes [it does](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Comment: @jdstankosky: Yeah, I just learned that :D

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 26: http://jsfiddle.net/BUdv6/ (Before submitting, open your dev tools, and you'll see that when you submit, it's trying to load `result.html`)

Comment: It is important to note that the attributes you're using are HTML5 spec. Make sure you have the declaration `<!doctype html>` and are using an HTML5 capable browser.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Chromium in Ubuntu. I have declared <!doctype html>.  And with `action="result.html"` as an attribute to form, there is now and "error loading page"

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat , yes <button> can have formaction: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the action and formaction attributes to the form and submit button, and I decided to code my page as an SPA (single page app) so I move to next page using jquery:

```
        $.mobile.changePage($('#result-page'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly state that as an attribute, i.e. an 'action' attribute in 'form'.

```
<form name="userdata" method="get" action="result.html">

    <input type="number" step="any" class="hiddenbutton" name="userVolume" value="" >

    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton" name="issubmitted" value="no" class="submitbutton" formmethod="get" formaction="result.html">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: With `action="result.html"` as an attribute to form, there is now an "error loading page"